# Disable Flex DateField component from user input

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, flex4, mxml

I have a DateField component in Flex and I want to stop any user input. If I set the editable to "false" then it stops users changed the bits of the DateField box. It does NOT however stop them from clicking on the calendar icon next to it and updating the date. Is it possible to disable this?

I basically want the component to be read only under some circumstances but not for it to have any alpha overlay. Therefore I want to use editable rather than enabled.

Thanks for any help
Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use enabled, and then set the styles `disabledColor` to `0x000000` and `disabledSkin` to `ScrollArrowSkin` (The default for DateField, upSkin)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jacob. I think I see what you mean. How can I set the style in action script? Or do can I only do it in mxml? Would what you are saying work also for dropdownlist? I will try with them once I can figure out how to do this in actionscript. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: In answer to my comment I have done this: endDate.setStyle("disabledColor", 0x000000);
        endDate.setStyle("disabledSkin", ScrollArrowSkin);

Comment: @user You got the actionscript setting. And yes, something similar would also work for dropdownlist. Though all you would need to do is set a custom skin. Make a copy of DropDownListSkin and remove `alpha.disabled=".5"`